M Chip Mac and pipenv with python 3.6
I have a project that requires Python 3.6 and uses pipenv, I have recently got a new machine and having a lot of difficulty getting pipenv to work.
From what I see python 3.6 is no longer supported by pipenv?
I have got python 3.6 installed using pyenv running under python. However pipenv seems to use it's own version and will not work anyway with older versions?
So, is there a way to install an older version of pipenv which does support python 3.6, I don't seem to be able to do this with brew or to easily convert the project to requirments.txt lets say, I'm not super familiar with python so little stumped.

Isn't it easier to try a more modern Python version, and ask in this site if you have some problems/incompatibilities? Try not use products after end-of-life when possible. From my personal experience since 3.6 upgrades are smooth (if libraries support them, but if they do not support them, warning about new Jia Tan problems).
